# Generate Unique Identifier that can distinguish ID(Foo::a()) from ID(Foo::b())

Tags: c++, c++11, uniqueidentifier, member-functions

Say I have:

```
struct S{
    void f(int);
    float g(int,int);
    void h(int);
}

#define UID(w) /* how to do it? */

cout << UID(S::f);
cout << UID(S::g);
cout << UID(S::h);
```

I need some way of creating a unique number, string or address for each member.

This is because I'm going to be using:

```
#define BIND(foo) Generate<decltype(&foo), &foo>::call

u = & BIND(S::f)
v = & BIND(S::g)
w = & BIND(S::h)
```

i.e. `BIND` generates an associated C-style function

Here is a sketch of the generator:

```
template< typename F f >
struct Generate {}

template < typename R,  typename ...Arg,  R(S::*target)(Arg...) >
struct Generate< R(S::*)(Arg...),target >
{
    static R call( PyObject* self, Arg... carg)
    {
        cout << ??? // the name, e.g. 'S::b'
```

I need this function to `cout` the name of the `S::foo` that generated it.

So the second half of the question is: how can I recover the same UID from inside `call`?

The reason I'm trying to create UIDs is so that I can make a:

```
static std::map<void*, std::string> names_map;
```

Then I can modify my:

```
#define BIND(foo) Generate<decltype(&foo), &foo>::call; \
                  names_map[ UID(foo) ] = std::string(#foo);

    static R call( PyObject* self, Arg... carg)
    {
        cout << names_map[ UID(  R(S::*target)(Arg...)  ) ];
```

But how to actually do this?

I've put together a testcase [on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5134532a1ce7f55) -- can anyone make it work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543306/platform-independent-guid-generation-in-c

Comment: A uuid is a COM detail.  It only applies to types, not functions.

Comment: @HansPassant, my bad for using the wrong terminology. I've reworded the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like an XY problem. What you actually need is a way to associate a particular type (`Generate<...>`) to something that can be used as a key in a map. There is a standard way to do that - it's called `std::type_index`.

```
static std::map<std::type_index, std::string> names_map;

/* ... */

template <typename R, typename... Arg, R(Base::*target)(Arg...)>
struct Generate< R(Base::*)(Arg...), target >
{
    static void call() 
    {
        std::cout << "TARG:" << names_map[ std::type_index( typeid(Generate) ) ] << std::endl;
    }
};

#define BIND(fp, cxx_target) \
                            fp = &Generate< decltype(&cxx_target), &cxx_target >::call; \
                            names_map[ std::type_index(typeid(Generate< decltype(&cxx_target), &cxx_target >)) ] = std::string(#cxx_target);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c0a32832c03ae13a).

Comment: That's fantastic - Thankyou! I just noticed it can be made symmetrical by using `std::type_index(typeid(decltype(x)))` -- [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3495a0357ee659d5) (is there any way to improve upon the #define?)

Comment: @Pi Don't do that - that indexes on the *type* of the pointer to member function only. Note how your first call is printing `TARG:Base::h` when it should print `TARG:Base::f`? The code in my answer indexes on the type of `Generate<...>`, which incorporates both the type of the pointer to member function and the *value*.

Comment: aiee. I should have looked at the output before posting that. [Fixed](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a6dee3e43e3dd0f2).